# How to set a function as function argument in Swift 3

Tags: swift

**Q**: Is it possible to pass a function as function argument in Swift 3?

To refactor my code, I want to have a global function. At the end of this function, there is a custom button that has an `action` argument.

```
let deleteButton = MIAlertController.Button(title: "cancel", 
                                            type: .cancel, 
                                            config: getDestructiveButtonConfig(),
                                            action: {
                                                print("completed")
                                            })
```

What I would like to do is something like, setting up a global function with a function as argument.

```
MyGlobalStuff.swift
...
func getButton(_ myFunc: func, _ title: String) {
    let deleteButton = MIAlertController.Button(title: title, 
                                            type: .cancel, 
                                            config: getDestructiveButtonConfig(),
                                            action: {
                                                myFunc // call here the function pass by argument
                                            })
}
```

Called by `getButton(..)` with the passed function within the same Class.

```
MyViewController.swift
...
getButton(myPrintFunc, "cancel")

func myPrintFunc() {
        print("completed")
}
```

Is something like that possible? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `Function Types as Parameter Types` in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: @Santosh your link does not cover my question. i'm not looking for closure or returned values

Comment: well. actually I needed a closure... I swear, I have tried it before. did not work. tried it again after the answers, worked... my bad. thank youf or your time

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can pass a function/closure as parameter of another function.

This is the syntax

```
func doSomething(closure: () -> ()) {
    closure()
}
```

here the function `doSomething` receives as parameter a closure with no params and no return type.

You can call doSomething with this syntax

```
doSomething(closure: { _ in print("Hello world") })
```

Or using the trailing closure syntax

```
doSomething { 
    print("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: closure does not work because then this code will get called the moment the getButton function has been called, not once the button has been pressed

Comment: @DavidSeek, why will it be executed the moment the getButton function has been called?

Comment: if i have a closure in getButton, it will get called the moment the function has been completed. but I need it to be called once the button has been pressed

Comment: Did you put it in `action` param of `MIAlertController.Button`?

Comment: okay. got it working. tried it with closure before, but it did not work. guess my bad. also I think, that your approach is the same as Luke's? `_ myFunc: () -> Void` is the same as `_ closure: () -> ()`

Answer (score 10):

Assuming

```
typealias Func = () -> Void
```

You can do:

```
func getButton(_ title: String, _ myFunc: Func) {
    let deleteButton = MIAlertController.Button(title: title, 
                                                type: .cancel, 
                                                config: getDestructiveButtonConfig(),
                                                action: {
                                                    myFunc()
                                                })
}
```

Or even:

```
func getButton(_ title: String, _ myFunc: Func) {
    let deleteButton = MIAlertController.Button(title: title, 
                                                type: .cancel, 
                                                config: getDestructiveButtonConfig(),
                                                action: myFunc
                                                )
}
```

Also, if you haven't noticed, I moved closure to the end of parameter list. This way it will allow advanced magic like:

```
getButton("X") { … }
```

instead of

```
getButton({ … }, "X")
```

Comment: uh. i like the typealias. thank you! upvote for that

Answer (score 6):

Functions are first class in swift so you can pass them like so:

```
func getButton(_ myFunc: () -> Void, _ title: String) {
```

You need to specify the signature of the function in the type, i.e. parameter types and return type

Comment: thank you, your approach worked just as good as appzYourLife's. giving him the checkmark, because he was faster. upvote for your time and help. thanks