# Adding action to a button which is added to a textfield by extension in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have to added a button on right side of textfield by extension

code is ---

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class TxtFieldCustom: UITextField {
 @IBInspectable var rightButtonImage: UIImage?
    {
    didSet
    {
        updateRightView()
    }
}
func updateRightView()
    {
        //for right Image
        if let image = rightButtonImage
        {
  let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 29, height: 29)
rightView = button
            rightViewMode = .always

        } else
        {
            rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never
            rightView = nil
        }
    }
```

button is showing like screenshot but I am confused how to set action to that button . I can't set it in extension file because I have different action fro different textfield...

[image]

Comment: May be this link helpful for you try it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467847/how-to-set-a-function-as-function-argument-in-swift-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467847/how-to-set-a-function-as-function-argument-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a target for the button and when that action is being called you should post a Notification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("buttonPressed"), object: nil)
```

Then in your ViewController you can add an observer and implement different actions.
With multiple UITextFields you pass userData with the Notification.

Comment: thanks...I did the same.                                                    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClick), for: .touchUpInside)
@objc func btnClick()
    {
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue:self.accessibilityLabel!) , object: nil)
    }