# Using closures as parameters without trailing closures Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When using trailing closure syntax it seems quite easy to [pass a function as a parameter of another function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467958/1800285).

However I want to do this WITHOUT using the trailing closure syntax

```
func doSomethingTwo(closure: (String) -> Void) {
    closure("AAA")
}

doSomethingTwo(closure: print("TEST") )
```

gives 
Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(String) -> Void'

I know that

```
doSomethingTwo{ (test: String) in
    print ("\(test)")
}
```

works, but want this without the trailing closure syntax.

This is not a homework problem, I am looking at tutorials and have done research that has not given me an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own print method to pass it as a parameter:

```
func doSomethingTwo(closure: (String) -> ()) {
    // when you call the closure you need to pass the string to be printed
    closure("TEST")
}
```

Define the method to print the string that will be passed to the closure:

```
let closure: (String) -> () = { print($0) }
```

Then you can call it as you wish:

```
doSomethingTwo(closure: closure)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function correctly. You should call it like this:

```
doSomethingTwo(closure: { (text) in
print(text)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call a function

```
doSomethingTwo()
```

If we follow the pattern, put `()` first, then comes with its parameter, you'll get something like this.

```
doSomethingTwo(closure: { (str) in
     print(str)
})
```

By the way, `Xcode` will helps you to complete. But if you don't want its help, when you have this, don't `tap`, type the rest by your own.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting this error you're probably missing an `=` sign

for e.g

```
yourClosure = { variable: VariableType in 
    print(variable)
}
```